# How do I get the contents of a label, if a checkbox is selected?

Tags: asp.net, listview, checkbox, webforms, label

I have a listview with multiple columns. One of the columns is a checkbox, another is a label. There are other columns but they're not really relevant to this issue. In the click event of a button on this page I want to read the value of the label if the checkbox adjacent to it is selected. How do I read the label contents?

The code I have so far is included below. The code runs but the checked status of the checkboxes is never found to be checked. I checked the itemTemplate to confirm the name and ensure this problem wasn't the result of a typo.

```
        CheckBox chkSelected;
        List<int> selectedIds = new List<int>();


        foreach (var x in lvPeople.Items)
        {
            chkSelected = (CheckBox)x.FindControl("IsAlumni");

            if (chkSelected.Checked)
            {
                int id = (int)lvPeople.DataKeys[x.DisplayIndex].Value;                    

                selectedIds.Add(id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're looking for a single control called "IsAlumni" multiple times?

Comment: If you look in Request.Forms, are the labels there? Checkboxes will only be submitted if they are checked.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code of your .aspx page?

Comment: Are you checking this on if(!(Page.IsPostback))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have something like this:

```
foreach (var x in lvPeople.Items)
{
    chkSelected = (CheckBox)x.FindControl("IsAlumni");

    if (chkSelected.Checked)
    {
        int id = (int)lvPeople.DataKeys[x.DisplayIndex].Value;

        var myLabel = (Label)x.FindControl("lblContactId");
        var myLabelContent = myLabel.Text;                  

        selectedIds.Add(id);
    }
}
```

For example, in the selected item event you could have this code:

```
CheckBox chkSelected =
           lvPeople.Items(lvPeople.SelectedIndex).FindControl("IsAlumni") as CheckBox;
```

Comment: Aren't Labels just rendered as Spans as they are not Input controls like a TextBox?  In my experience, on postback, you'll never get the value from a Label.  You'd have to load the text into a textbox and then do var myTxt = (TextBox)x.FindControl("txtContactID");